# Conditional and normal pobability

Tags: probability-distributions

The wingspan of a species of pigeon is normally distributed with mean 60 cm and standard deviation 6 cm. A pigeon of this species is chosen at random.
a) Find the probability that its wingspan is greater than 50 cm.
b) Given that this pigeon's wingspan is greater than 50 cm, find the probability that it is greater than 55 cm.

I was able to calculate the answer for part a 0.952 without any trouble, but the process for part b is confusing. The answer is 0.838. We have briefly studied conditional probabilities and currently on normal probabilities. This is what I came up with, but don't know how to justify adding the probabilities in the numerator and also subtracting from 1.

P(55,50) = {[P(55) + P(50)]/P(50)} - 1

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the definition of conditional probability:

$$P(\text{wingspan}> 55| \text{wingspan} > 50)  = \frac{P(\text{wingspan}>55\text{ and wingspan}>50)}{P(\text{wingspan}>50)}$$

Now, the probability that the wingspan is greater than $55$ **and** greater than $50$ can be simplified...